# Pods on google kubernetes engine pending?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, jupyterhub

Trying to set up the jupyterhub server on Google Kubernetes following this [tutorial](https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/create-k8s-cluster.html). Everything went through fine. But when I install jupyterhub/jupyterhub image with helm, it's always showing the pods are pending:

```
kubectl --namespace=jupyter-server get pod

NAME                     READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
hub-6dbd4df8b8-nqvnf     0/1       Pending   0          17h
proxy-7bb666576c-fx726   0/2       Pending   0          17h
```

Even after 17 hours.

The `helm` version is `2.6.2` as suggested in the [tutorial](https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup-helm.html). And I am using 3 `f1-micro` instances in the kubernetes cluster. Are these instances too small?  Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try describing the pod, and the describing the nodes in the cluster, to get more info about why exactly they're still pending:

```
kubectl describe po/hub-6dbd4df8b8-nqvnf -n jupyter-server
kubectl describe po/proxy-7bb666576c-fx726 -n jupyter-server

kubectl describe nodes
```

Comment: Can you provide the info regarding the problem you had? This could help future users looking this answer